# Check connection between nodes if there is no 'ping' command

Tags: networking, ping

I have two minimalistic docker containers with no 'ping' command. How do I check whether there is connectivity between those two?

Comment: telnet, nmap, wget, bash, lynx, w3m, netcat, ftp, ssh...

Comment: @IporSircer Thank you for your suggestions but there are no such tools either.

Comment: @IporSircer they are filebeat and logstash. They used to work well but recently they stopped working, so I wonder it is because the connectivity problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "docker container inspect" and "ping" on the docker host itself to verify the containers have the addressing and connectivity you expect. Verify that you can ping the docker container from the host.

You can use a networking tool such as wireshark or tcpdump on the path between the containers to inspect traffic. You can e.g., run on the docker host, run tcpdump on the bridge a container is on.

You can also run containers that have network tools such as ping on the same docker bridges your problematic containers are on, in order to reproduce and troubleshoot your issue. Example: run an ubuntu or alpine container attached to the same docker network as e.g., the filebeat container. Test network connectivity to the destination (elasticsearch?) using ping and curl.

Finally, you can install or copy a ping binary to your running containers. Download busybox and "docker cp" the binary into the container. Then "docker exec" to run it in the container.

Comment: Thank you, your solution is rather complex but I like it.